# Matrix row-echelon form issue

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra) I understand most of the steps in:

[image]

But why the last step? Isn't enough to have the following?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column and row space are equal. So $rankcolumn=rankrow$. What you got on the last step is obtaining Reduced Row Echelon Form. In this case it is redundant to find them because it is obvious that on which columns you have pivot entries. So you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes for the row reduced echelon form the last step is not necessary to find the pivot columns.